# html5 Label with line breaking

Tags: html, label, line-breaks

how to make a label to recognize \n´s inside a string?

```
<label>
a
b
</label>
```

Is there a way to make it display the string as it is, via some css property? I mean, in this case, display it in two different lines

Answer (score 0):

It´s not a generic answer, but with angularjs, it could be achieved using ng-bind-html directive